# Laurent Expansion of $f(z)=\frac{1}{z^2(1-z)}$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

> I am trying to find two distinct Laurent expansions of $f(z)=\frac{1}{z^2(1-z)},$
>   in powers of $z$.

My attempt:

I believe I have found one Laurent expansion of the region $0<|z|<1$.
\begin{align}
f(z)&=\frac{1}{z^2(1-z)} \\
&=\frac{1}{z}+\frac{1}{z^2}+\frac{1}{1-z} \\
&=\sum_{n=-2}^{\infty} z^n
\end{align}
But I cannot find a second expansion. I know the region for this expansion is $|z|>1$. The answer provided is $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{-3} (-1)^nz^n$, but I don't understand the method of getting to this answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f(z)=-\frac 1 {z^{3}} \frac 1 {1-\frac 1 z}=-\frac 1 {z^{3}} (1+\frac1 z +\frac 1 {z^{2}}+...)$ for $|z| >1$.

Comment: For $|z|>1$, do we only consider $\frac{1}{1-z}$?

Comment: for instance, if we have $$f(z)=\frac{3}{(z-2)(z+1)},$$ for the region $|z-1|<1$, we only consider $\frac{1}{z-2}$. Why is that?